# Using Polymer in a Dart Chrome App

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer

I am trying to build an app with Dart and Polymer. But polymer scripts seem to be using eval() in web_components/platform.js:32. Has anyone managed to do this? I tried to change CSP but that helped in first place.

Does anyone have a working example?

Regards and Thanks
Robert

**EDIT**

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Animatr app",
  "version": "1",

  "author": "Robert Hartung",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons": {"128": "animatr_icon.png"},

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' unsafe-inline;"
}
```

main.html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animatr app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animatr_chrome_app.css">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script>
    <script src="my_chrome_app.dart" type="application/dart;component=1"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

ERROR:

```dart
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. (chrome-extension://ofkfcbfhgkoglbgldcdokficikimdjji/packages/web_components/platform.js:32)
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: animatr_app
description: A sample Chrome packaged application
dependencies:
  chrome: any
  polymer: any
transformers:
- chrome
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - app/animatr_chrome_app.html
    csp: 'true'
```

The app does not recognize polymer elements correctly.

Comment: Can you please add more information (error message, pubspec.yaml, package structure, manifest.json, ...)

Comment: Does it run fine on Dartium? (without being build to js)

Comment: I only tried with pure dart and chromium. Starting the app from the dart editor.

Comment: I edited my post to show you the code.

Comment: I don't know the details, but a Polymer tool called Vulcanizer is needed to make Polymer CSP-compliant. I think the idea is it concatenates all the components into a single include to avoid the need to dynamically include further JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at https://github.com/dart-lang/spark/tree/master/ide for an example Dart Chrome-Packaged-App. They also make heavily use of Polymer.

Maybe this is related https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/252

It seems this is the related Dart bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17409

Comment: This surely is related, thank you Günter! Let's see if we can find a solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I have been struggling with the same issue, trying to run the simple wizard generated polymer app (the one with the counter) as a chrome packaged app.
I have finally managed to at least run the javascript built version of it, trying to understand the *csp* issues.
For many reason, it sounds like it cannot run *native* as the packaged app is loaded from the file system and not through pub serve. Loading the *unpackaged extension* from `web/build` was not working neither as is. The solution was to load xxx.html_bootstrap.dart.**precompiled.js** instead of xxx.html_bootstrap.js from the generated html file
What i did was:

- **remove** the **chrome** transformer as the polymer transformer already replace the dart script reference by a javascript script reference
- add **csp: true** in the polymer transformer option (although it did work without it)
- to avoid having to change manually the generated html to load the precompiled.js version, I wrote a simple transformer.
- I can then load in Chrome (does not have to be Dartium as it is javascript) the unpacked extension from `web/build` once I run `pub build` (release mode needed)

I now simply have this warning:

```
Deprecation: Automatic generation of output for Content Security
Policy is deprecated and will be removed with the next development
release. Use the --csp option to generate CSP restricted output.
```

which means likely I would have to find a new hack soon...