# How to convert Dart to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dart

The Dart app runs fine in Dartium, but I would like to convert it to JS.

`C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart2js --out=test.js main.dart` generates JS from:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector('#myid').text = 'Wake up, sleepy head!';
}
```

Then I add it to the `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="myid">hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it in Firefox, it doesn't work. It shows only "Hello" on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dart2js` is usually not the straight-forward way to generated JS from Dart.
Normally you just run `pub build` in your project directory. 
Ensure you have your `pubspec.yaml` configured properly `csp: true` (for Chrome apps [Using Polymer in a Dart Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710329), [Chrome App CSP violation after Dart/Polymer transform/compile to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511346))

Comment: How to use pub on Windows? Should I add Dart SDK folder to PATH? And then run pub in myAppFolder? How I can generate empty `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yup, add `dart-sdk/bin` to the path. Also DartEditor contains context menus, I think on `pubspec.yaml` or in tools menu (It's a while I used it).

Comment: Just open your pubspec.yaml and on the right there is `run pub build`.

Comment: And what next? Which js file I should include?

Comment: If you have an `xxx.html` page (`index.html` or whatever name you choose) with a Dart script tag in `web` you get the same `xxx.html` output to `build/web/xxx.html` with the JS script tags already properly set.

Comment: What dir organization should be for pure dart script + and html file? It's look like it have not proper structure and in result needed files not coping to `build/web/` folder

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your last comment. For details about the standard Pub package layout see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html . For a simple Dart web application put your files in `your_package_dir/web`. When running `pub build` the output is then generated in `your_package_dir/build/web`

Comment: After running pub build I can't find any index.html file compiled with JS:
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?z3494kz5gl9q

Comment: You have to put your source files into `web` as mentioned above.